# latex padding / margin hell

Tags: latex, padding, margin

I have been wrestling with a latex table for far too long.  I need a table that has has centered headers, and body cells that contain text that may wrap around.  Because of the wrap-around requirement, i'm using p{xxx} instead of l for specifying cell widths.  The problem this causes is that cell contents are not left justified, so the look like spaced-out junk.  To fix this problem I'm using \flushleft for each cell.  This does left justify contents, but puts in a ton of white space above and below the contents of the cell.  Is there a way to stop \flushleft (or \center for that matter) to stop adding copious amounts of verical whitespace?

thanks

```
\begin{landscape}
    \centering
    % using p{xxx} here to wrap long text instead of overflowing it
    \begin{longtable}{ | p{4cm} || p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{3cm} | p{3cm} |}
        \hline
         & 
        % these are table headings.  the \center is causing a ton of whitespace as well
        \begin{center} \textbf{HTC HD2} \end{center} & 
        \begin{center} \textbf{Motorola Milestone} \end{center} & 
        \begin{center} \textbf{Nokia N900} \end{center} & 
        \begin{center} \textbf{RIM Blackberry Bold 9700} \end{center} &
        \begin{center} \textbf{Apple iPhone 3GS} \end{center} \\
        \hline
        \hline
        % using flushleft here to left-justify, but again it is causing a ton of white space above and below cell contents.
        \begin{flushleft}OS / Platform \end{flushleft}& 
        \begin{flushleft}Windows Mobile 6.5 \end{flushleft}& 
        \begin{flushleft}Google Android 2.1 \end{flushleft}& 
        \begin{flushleft}Maemo \end{flushleft}& 
        \begin{flushleft}Blackberry OS 5.0 \end{flushleft}& 
        \begin{flushleft}iPhone OS 3.1 \end{flushleft} \\           
        \hline
```

Edit:

Thanks for the answers so far. I thought I found a solution that works, but these problems still exist:

- using \raggedright stops long words from being hyphenated.  This looks pretty bad when a cell contains a bunch of lines with only one word in them.
- using \raggedright only works if you end it with a blank line.  This causes every cell to have a completely blank line at the bottom of it.  This was what i was trying to avoid in the first place.

  ```
      {Display} & 
      {\raggedright 4.3 inch, 800 x 400 resolution} & 
      {\raggedright 3.7 inch, 854 x 480 resolution} & 
      {\raggedright 3.5 inch, 800 x 480 resolution} & 
      {\raggedright 2.44 inch, 320 x 480 resolution} & 
      {\raggedright 3.5 inch, 480 x 320 resolution} \\            
      \hline
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be fine to just specify how you want the body cells formated and
change only the headers to centered with `multicolumn`. That way you don't
have to mess with too many cells like you do right now.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l|p{2cm}|p{2cm}}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} \\
    1 & {Some longer text} & {Some other text}\\
    2 & {Some longer text} & {Some other text}\\
    3 & {Some longer text} & {Some other text}\\
    4 & {Some longer text} & {Some other text}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was pondering about (a variant on) this approach but not sure whether it would work. Thanks for clearing this out. It sure is a more elegant solution than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most elegant solution, but the `\centering` and `\raggedright` commands corresponds to the `center` and `flushleft` environments and don't come with the increased margins.

If I come across a nicer solution I will post it, but this *could* work I think.

Comment: can you post a snippet that shows how to use ruggedright? somebody else suggested it as well, but I have had no luck getting it to work.  Does it need to be inside an environment or something?  Thanks for the help

Comment: nice, I got this to work with raggedright.  Incredibly hacky though, i had to add an extra blank line after each string of text, and wrap everything with {}.... oh latex.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @honk's example, i think you'd want this:

\documentclass{article}

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}l|>{\raggedright}p{2cm}|>{\raggedright}p{2cm}|}
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{A} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{B} &
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{C} \\
    1 & Some longer text & Some other text\\
    2 & Some longer text & Some other text\\
    3 & Some longer text & Some other text\\
    4 & Some longer text & Some other text \\
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Words still won't be hyphenated, but this should solve the blank line problem you're having.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use p options in the column alignment specification, but use l instead.  Then in each heading, use `\hfill Somephone \hfill`, and in each body cell, use `\vbox to 3cm {About text}`.  Doing so should minimise excess padding.